# MySQL: Get the weekly count of every user in table

Tags: mysql

I'm a pretty newbie in MySQL and I don't have any idea on how to get the weekly count of every user in my table.

I have a table that looks like this.

| user_id | when_added |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | September 1, 2021 |
| 1 | September 4, 2021 |
| 1 | September 9, 2021 |
| 2 | September 4, 2021 |

What this does is I insert a row every time a particular user views a video.

I'm trying to get a result that looks like this.

| user_id | week | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Sept 1 - Sept 7 | 2 |
| 1 | Sept 8 - Sept 14 | 1 |
| 2 | Sept 1 - Sept 7 | 1 |

Is it possible in Mysql? Thanks

Comment: Use `COUNT(*)` and `GROUP BY YEARWEEK(when_added)`

Comment: Can you share the table structure?

Comment: Hello @Barmar, unfortunately, it only gives me the count of rows of my table.

Comment: @glovemobile actually my when_added is unix timestamp and the user_id is int.

Comment: `GROUP BY user_id, YEARWEEK(when_added)`

Comment: These are just hints, I'm not going to write the whole thing for you.

Comment: is it calendar week or month wise week like 1-7, 8-14, 15-21, 22-28, 28+